# Unix/Bash: Redirect results of find command so files are used as input for other command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I've got a directory structure that contains many different files named foo.sql.  I want to be able to cd into this directory & issue a command like the following:

```
find . -name "foo.sql" -exec mysql -uUserName -pUserPasswd < {} \;
```

where {} is the relative path to each foo.sql file.  Basically, I want:

```
mysql -uUserName -pUserPasswd < path/to/foo.sql
```

to be run once for each foo.sql file under my subdirectory.  I've tried Google & it's been not much help.  Ideally this would be part of a UNIX shell script.

Thanks in advance, & sorry if it's been asked before.

Answer (score 1):

The `-exec` option doesn't run a shell, so it can't process shell operators like redirection. Try this:

```
find . -name "foo.sql" -exec cat {} + | mysql -uUserName -pUserPasswd
```

`cat {}` will write the contents of all the files to the pipe, which will then be read by `mysql`.

Comment: This (like @keshlam's answer) runs a single instance of `mysql`, and feeds it all of the .sql files concatenated together. Is this what's needed?

Comment: In most cases the results will be the same. If he really needs to run separate instances, he can say so and I can come up with an answer that does it.

Answer (score 0):

Or, just to point out another approach:

```
find . | xargs cat | mysql etcetera
```

xargs is a generic pipe operation roughly equivalent to find's '-exec'. It has some advantages, some disadvantages, depending on what you're doing. Intend to use it because i'm often filtering the list of found files in an earlier pipeline stage before operating on them.

There are also other ways of assembling such command lines. One nice thing about Unix's generic toolkits is that there are usually multiple solutions, each with its own tradeoffs.

Comment: He wants to run a command that gets the input from stdin, not a filename argument

Comment: If so, then yes, i misread. There are multiple solutions to most Unix tasks, of course.

Comment: But this solution won't work for him. The `mysql` command doesn't take a filename argument.

Comment: Edited. Better? Or am I still misreading? (It's late and i should fall over.)

Comment: Yes, that's similar to my answer